# Vue Js infinite loop marquee (horizontal bar)

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need recommendations on how to build an infinite loop marquee from my vue js code, or at least how to use Vue Js and jQuery for this specific project.

My project Fiddle is as follows: https://jsfiddle.net/jackbauer/xz5wv617/7

It is working and what it does is creating a crypto currency horizontal bar, but now I need to know how to make it slide from right to left, in an infinite loop, and perhaps even add navigation controls. I tried searching for something like that in the The Progressive JavaScript Framework (https://vuejs.org/) but I couldn't find anything related to horizontal animation.

The result I'm trying to achieve is the same as in this jQuery plugin: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Horizontal-Text-Scrolling-Simple-Marquee/

I've even tried risking using Vue js and jQuery, with no success: https://jsfiddle.net/jackbauer/xz5wv617/14

Maybe I should write a code that makes the vue get fully executed, only then the jQuery code will execute?

All my code is available in the two fiddles that I've just posted, but just in case, here's my javascript:

```
    // common number filters
Vue.filter( 'toFixed', ( num, asset ) => {
  if ( typeof asset === 'number' ) return Number( num ).toFixed( asset );
  return Number( num ).toFixed( ( asset === 'USDT' ) ? 3 : 8 );
});
Vue.filter( 'toMoney', num => {
  return Number( num ).toFixed( 0 ).replace( /./g, ( c, i, a ) => {
    return i && c !== "." && ( ( a.length - i ) % 3 === 0 ) ? ',' + c : c;
  });
});

// component for creating line chart
Vue.component( 'linechart', {
  props: {
    width: { type: Number, default: 400, required: true },
    height: { type: Number, default: 40, required: true },
    values: { type: Array, default: [], required: true },
  },
  data() {
    return { cx: 0, cy: 0 };
  },
  computed: {
    viewBox() {
      return '0 0 '+ this.width +' '+ this.height;
    },
    chartPoints() {
      let data = this.getPoints();
      let last = data.length ? data[ data.length - 1 ] : { x: 0, y: 0 };
      let list = data.map( d => ( d.x - 10 ) +','+ d.y );
      this.cx  = last.x - 5;
      this.cy  = last.y;
      return list.join( ' ' );
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getPoints() {
      this.width  = parseFloat( this.width ) || 0;
      this.height = parseFloat( this.height ) || 0;
      let min     = this.values.reduce( ( min, val ) => val < min ? val : min, this.values[ 0 ] );
      let max     = this.values.reduce( ( max, val ) => val > max ? val : max, this.values[ 0 ] );
      let len     = this.values.length;
      let half    = this.height / 2;
      let range   = ( max > min ) ? ( max - min ) : this.height;
      let gap     = ( len > 1 ) ? ( this.width / ( len - 1 ) ) : 1;
      let points  = [];

      for ( let i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
        let d = this.values[ i ];
        let val = 2 * ( ( d - min ) / range - 0.5 );
        let x = i * gap;
        let y = -val * half * 0.8 + half;
        points.push( { x, y } );
      }
      return points;
    }
  },
  template: `
  <svg :viewBox="viewBox" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polyline class="cryptocolor" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" :points="chartPoints" />
    <circle class="cryptocolor" :cx="cx" :cy="cy" r="4" fill="#fff" stroke="none" />
  </svg>`,
});

// vue instance
new Vue({
  // mount point
  el: '#app',

  // app data
  data: {
    endpoint : 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!ticker@arr',
    iconbase : 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rainner/binance-watch/master/public/images/icons/',
    cache    : {},             // coins data cache
    coins    : [],             // live coin list from api
    asset    : 'USDT',          // filter by base asset pair
    search   : '',             // filter by search string
    sort     : 'Price',  // sort by param
    order    : 'desc',         // sort order ( asc, desc )
    limit    : 50,             // limit list 
    status   : 0,              // socket status ( 0: closed, 1: open, 2: active, -1: error )
    sock     : null,           // socket inst
    cx       : 0,
    cy       : 0,
  },

  // computed methods
  computed: {

    // process coins list
    coinsList() {
      let list = this.coins.slice();
      let search = this.search.replace( /[^\s\w\-\.]+/g, '' ).replace( /[\r\s\t\n]+/g, ' ' ).trim();

      if ( this.asset ) {
        list = list.filter( i => i.asset === this.asset );
      }
      if ( search && search.length > 1 ) {
        let reg = new RegExp( '^('+ search +')', 'i' );
        list = list.filter( i => reg.test( i.token ) );
      }
      if ( this.sort ) {
        list = this.sortList( list, this.sort, this.order );
      }
      if ( this.limit ) {
        list = list.slice( 0, this.limit );
      }
      return list;
    },

    // show socket connection loader
    loaderVisible() {
      return ( this.status === 2 ) ? false : true;
    },

    // sort-by label for buttons, etc
    sortLabel() {
      switch ( this.sort ) {

        case 'token'       :  return 'Token';
        case 'percent'     :  return 'Percent';
        case 'close'       :  return 'Price';
        case 'change'      :  return 'Change';
        case 'assetVolume' :  return 'Volume';
        case 'tokenVolume' :  return 'Volume';
        case 'trades'      :  return 'Trades';
        default            :  return 'Default';
      }
    },
  },

  // custom methods
  methods: {

    // apply sorting and toggle order
    sortBy( key, order ) {
      if ( this.sort !== key ) { this.order = order || 'asc'; }
      else { this.order = ( this.order === 'asc' ) ? 'desc' : 'asc'; }
      this.sort = key;
    },

    // filter by asset
    filterAsset( asset ) {
      this.asset = String( asset || 'BTC' );
    },

    // set list limit
    setLimit( limit ) {
      this.limit = parseInt( limit ) || 0;
    },

    // on socket connected
    onSockOpen( e ) {
      this.status = 1; // open
      console.info( 'WebSocketInfo:', 'Connection open ('+ this.endpoint +').' );
    },

    // on socket closed
    onSockClose( e ) {
      this.status = 0; // closed
      console.info( 'WebSocketInfo:', 'Connection closed ('+ this.endpoint +').' );
      setTimeout( this.sockInit, 10000 ); // try again
    },

    // on socket error
    onSockError( err ) {
      this.status = -1; // error
      console.error( 'WebSocketError:', err.message || err );
      setTimeout( this.sockInit, 10000 ); // try again
    },

    // process data from socket
    onSockData( e ) {
      let list = JSON.parse( e.data ) || [];

      for ( let item of list ) {
        // cleanup data for each coin
        let c = this.getCoinData( item );
        // keep to up 100 previous close prices in hostiry for each coin
        c.history = this.cache.hasOwnProperty( c.symbol ) ? this.cache[ c.symbol ].history : this.fakeHistory( c.close );
        if ( c.history.length > 100 ) c.history = c.history.slice( c.history.length - 100 );
        c.history.push( c.close );
        // add coin data to cache
        this.cache[ c.symbol ] = c;
      }
      // convert cache object to final prices list for each symbol
      this.coins = Object.keys( this.cache ).map( s => this.cache[ s ] );
      this.status = 2; // active
    },

    // start socket connection
    sockInit() {
      if ( this.status > 0 ) return;
      try {
        this.status = 0; // closed
        this.sock = new WebSocket( this.endpoint );
        this.sock.addEventListener( 'open', this.onSockOpen );
        this.sock.addEventListener( 'close', this.onSockClose );
        this.sock.addEventListener( 'error', this.onSockError );
        this.sock.addEventListener( 'message', this.onSockData );
      }
      catch( err ) {
        console.error( 'WebSocketError:', err.message || err );
        this.status = -1; // error
        this.sock = null;
      }
    },

    // start socket connection
    sockClose() {
      if ( this.sock ) {
        this.sock.close();
      }
    },

    // come up with some fake history prices to fill in the initial line chart
    fakeHistory( close ) {
      let num = close * 0.0001; // faction of current price
      let min = -Math.abs( num );
      let max = Math.abs( num );
      let out = [];

      for ( let i = 0; i < 50; ++i ) {
        let rand = Math.random() * ( max - min ) + min;
        out.push( close + rand );
      }
      return out;
    },

    // finalize data for each coin from socket
    getCoinData( item ) {
      let reg         = /^([A-Z]+)(BTC|ETH|BNB|USDT|TUSD)$/;
      let symbol      = String( item.s ).replace( /[^\w\-]+/g, '' ).toUpperCase();
      let token       = symbol.replace( reg, '$1' );
      let asset       = symbol.replace( reg, '$2' );
      let name        = token;
      let pair        = token +'/'+ asset;
      let icon        = this.iconbase + token.toLowerCase() + '_.png';
      let open        = parseFloat( item.o );
      let high        = parseFloat( item.h );
      let low         = parseFloat( item.l );
      let close       = parseFloat( item.c );
      let change      = parseFloat( item.p );
      let percent     = parseFloat( item.P );
      let trades      = parseInt( item.n );
      let tokenVolume = Math.round( item.v );
      let assetVolume = Math.round( item.q );
      let sign        = ( percent >= 0 ) ? '+' : '';
      let arrow       = ( percent >= 0 ) ? '▲' : '▼';
      let info        = [ pair, close.toFixed( 8 ), '(', arrow, sign + percent.toFixed( 2 ) +'%', '|', sign + change.toFixed( 8 ), ')' ].join( ' ' );
      let style       = '';

      if ( percent > 0 ) style = 'cryptogain';
      if ( percent < 0 ) style = 'cryptoloss';

      return { symbol, token, asset, name, pair, icon, open, high, low, close, change, percent, trades, tokenVolume, assetVolume, sign, arrow, style, info };
    },
    // sort an array by key and order
    sortList( list, key, order ) {
      return list.sort( ( a, b ) => {
        let _a = a[ key ];
        let _b = b[ key ];

        if ( _a && _b ) {
          _a = ( typeof _a === 'string' ) ? _a.toUpperCase() : _a;
          _b = ( typeof _b === 'string' ) ? _b.toUpperCase() : _b;

          if ( order === 'asc' ) {
            if ( _a < _b ) return -1;
            if ( _a > _b ) return 1;
          }
          if ( order === 'desc' ) {
            if ( _a > _b ) return -1;
            if ( _a < _b ) return 1;
          }
        }
        return 0;
      });
    },
  },
    // app mounted
  mounted() {
    this.sockInit();
  },

  // app destroyed
  destroyed() {
    this.sockClose();
  }
});



// BEGIN SLIDER

// ---------------------------------
// ---------- SimpleMarquee ----------
// ---------------------------------
//Copyright (C) 2016  Fabian Valle 
//An easy to implement marquee plugin. I know its easy because even I can use it.
//Forked from: https://github.com/conradfeyt/Simple-Marquee
//Re-Written by: Fabian Valle (www.fabian-valle.com) (www.obliviocompany.com)
// 
// ------------------------
// Structure //
//
//  *********************************** - marque-container - *************************************
//  *                                                                                            *
//  *   ******************************* ******************************************************   *
//  *   *                             * *                                                    *   *
//  *   * - marquee-content-sibling - * *                 - marquee-content -                *   *
//  *   *                             * *                                                    *   *
//  *   ******************************* ******************************************************   *
//  *                                                                                            *
//  **********************************************************************************************
//
//// Usage //
//  
//    Only need to call the createMarquee() function,
//    if desired, pass through the following paramaters:
//
//    $1 duration:                   controls the speed at which the marquee moves
//
//    $2 padding:                    right margin between consecutive marquees. 
//
//    $3 marquee_class:             the actual div or span that will be used to create the marquee - 
//                                   multiple marquee items may be created using this item's content. 
//                                   This item will be removed from the dom
//
//    $4 container_class:           the container div in which the marquee content will animate. 
//
//    $5 marquee-content-sibling :   (optional argument) a sibling item to the marqueed item  that 
//                                   affects the end point position and available space inside the 
//                                   container. 
//
//    $6 hover:                     Boolean to indicate whether pause on hover should is required. 
;(function ($, window, document, undefined){
    var pluginName = 'SimpleMarquee';

    function Plugin (element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this._defaults = $.fn.SimpleMarquee.defaults;
        this.settings = $.extend( {}, this._defaults, options );
        this.marqueeSpawned = [];
        this.marqueeHovered = false;
        this.documentHasFocus = false;        
        //
        this.counter = 0;

        this.timeLeft = 0;
        this.currentPos = 0;
        this.distanceLeft = 0;
        this.totalDistance = 0;
        this.contentWidth = 0;
        this.endPoint = 0;
        this.duration = 0;
        this.hovered = false;
        this.padding = 0;
        
        
        this.init();
    }
    function marqueeObj(newElement){
        this.el=newElement;
        this.counter=0;
        this.name="";
        this.timeTop=0;
        this.currentPos=0;
        this.distanceTop=0;
        this.totalDistance=0;
        this.contentWidth=0;
        this.endPoint=0;
        this.duration=0;
        this.hovered=false;
        this.padding=0;
    }
    //methods for plugin
    $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {

        // Initialization logic
        init: function () {
            this.buildCache();
            this.bindEvents();
            var config = this.settings;
            //init marquee
            if($(config.marquee_class).width() == 0){
                console.error('FATAL: marquee css or children css not correct. Width is either set to 0 or the element is collapsing. Make sure overflow is set on the marquee, and the children are postitioned relatively');
                return;
            }
    
            if(typeof $(config.marquee_class) === 'undefined'){
                console.error('FATAL: marquee class not valid');
                return;
            }
    
            if(typeof $(config.container_class) === 'undefined'){
                console.error('FATAL: marquee container class not valid');
                return;
            }
    
            if(config.sibling_class != 0 && typeof $(config.sibling_class) === 'undefined'){
                console.error('FATAL: sibling class container class not valid');
                return;
            }
            
                if (config.autostart)
                {
                    this.documentHasFocus = true;
                }
            //create the Marquee
            this.createMarquee();
        },

        // Remove plugin instance completely
        destroy: function() {
            this.unbindEvents();
            this.$element.removeData();
        },

        // Cache DOM nodes for performance
        buildCache: function () {
            this.$element = $(this.element);
        },

        // Bind events that trigger methods
        bindEvents: function() {
            var plugin = this;
            $(window).on('focus',function(){
                plugin.documentHasFocus = true;
                for (var key in plugin.marqueeSpawned){
                  plugin.marqueeManager(plugin.marqueeSpawned[key]);   
                } 
            });
            $(window).on('blur',function(){
                plugin.documentHasFocus = false;
                for (var key in plugin.marqueeSpawned){
                    plugin.marqueeSpawned[key].el.clearQueue().stop(); 
                    plugin.marqueeSpawned[key].hovered = true;
                }
            });

        },

        // Unbind events that trigger methods
        unbindEvents: function() {
            $(window).off('blur focus');
        },
        getPosition: function(elName){
            this.currentPos = parseInt($(elName).css('left'));
            return this.currentPos;
        },
        createMarquee: function(){
            var plugin = this;
            var config = plugin.settings;
            var marqueeContent =  $(config.marquee_class).html();
            var containerWidth = $(config.container_class).width();
            var contentWidth = $(config.marquee_class).width();
            
            var widthToIgnore = 0;
            if (config.sibling_class != 0){ 
                widthToIgnore = $(config.sibling_class).width();
            } 
            
            var spawnAmount = Math.ceil(containerWidth / contentWidth);
            
            $(config.marquee_class).remove();

            if(spawnAmount<=2){
                spawnAmount = 3;
            } else {
              spawnAmount++;
            }

            var totalContentWidth = (contentWidth + config.padding)*spawnAmount;

            var endPoint = -(totalContentWidth - containerWidth);

            var totalDistance =  containerWidth - endPoint;
            
            
            
            
            for (var i = 0; i < spawnAmount; i++) {
                
                var newElement = false;
                
                if(config.hover == true){

                  
                  newElement = $('<div class="marquee-' + (i+1) + '">' + marqueeContent + '</div>')        
                  .mouseenter(function() {


                    if ((plugin.documentHasFocus == true) && (plugin.marqueeHovered == false)){
                      plugin.marqueeHovered = true;

                      for (var key in plugin.marqueeSpawned){
                        plugin.marqueeSpawned[key].el.clearQueue().stop(); 
                        plugin.marqueeSpawned[key].hovered = true;
                      }
                      

                    }

                  })
                  .mouseleave(function() {


                      if ((plugin.documentHasFocus == true) && (plugin.marqueeHovered == true)){

                        for (var key in plugin.marqueeSpawned){
                          plugin.marqueeManager(plugin.marqueeSpawned[key]);   
                        } 

                        plugin.marqueeHovered = false;
                      } 
                  });

                } else {

                  newElement = $('<div class="marquee-' + (i+1) + '">' + marqueeContent + '</div>') ;   

                }

                plugin.marqueeSpawned[i] = new marqueeObj(newElement);

                $(config.container_class).append(newElement);

                plugin.marqueeSpawned[i].currentPos = (widthToIgnore + (contentWidth*i))+(config.padding*i);  //initial positioning
                plugin.marqueeSpawned[i].name = '.marquee-'+(i+1); 

                plugin.marqueeSpawned[i].totalDistance = totalDistance;  
                plugin.marqueeSpawned[i].containerWidth = containerWidth;  
                plugin.marqueeSpawned[i].contentWidth = contentWidth;  
                plugin.marqueeSpawned[i].endPoint = endPoint;  
                plugin.marqueeSpawned[i].duration = config.duration;  
                plugin.marqueeSpawned[i].padding = config.padding;  

                plugin.marqueeSpawned[i].el.css('left', plugin.marqueeSpawned[i].currentPos+config.padding +'px'); //setting left according to postition

                 if (plugin.documentHasFocus == true){
                  plugin.marqueeManager(plugin.marqueeSpawned[i]);
                }

            }
            //end for
            
            if(document.hasFocus()){
                 plugin.documentHasFocus = true;
            }else{
                plugin.documentHasFocus = false;
            }
            
        },
        marqueeManager: function(marqueed_el){
            var plugin = this;
            var elName = marqueed_el.name;
            if (marqueed_el.hovered == false) { 

                if (marqueed_el.counter > 0) {  //this is not the first loop
                  
                      marqueed_el.timeLeft = marqueed_el.duration;
                      marqueed_el.el.css('left', marqueed_el.containerWidth +'px'); //setting margin 
                      marqueed_el.currentPos = marqueed_el.containerWidth; 
                      marqueed_el.distanceLeft = marqueed_el.totalDistance - (marqueed_el.containerWidth - plugin.getPosition(elName));

                } else {    // this is the first loop
                  
                  marqueed_el.timeLeft = (((marqueed_el.totalDistance - (marqueed_el.containerWidth - plugin.getPosition(elName)))/ marqueed_el.totalDistance)) * marqueed_el.duration;
                }

            } else {
                  marqueed_el.hovered = false;
                  marqueed_el.currentPos = parseInt(marqueed_el.el.css('left'));
                  marqueed_el.distanceLeft = marqueed_el.totalDistance - (marqueed_el.containerWidth - plugin.getPosition(elName));
                  marqueed_el.timeLeft = (((marqueed_el.totalDistance - (marqueed_el.containerWidth - marqueed_el.currentPos))/ marqueed_el.totalDistance)) * marqueed_el.duration;
            }

            plugin.marqueeAnim(marqueed_el);
        },
        marqueeAnim: function(marqueeObject){
            var plugin = this;
            marqueeObject.counter++;
            marqueeObject.el.clearQueue().animate(
                    {'left': marqueeObject.endPoint+'px'}, 
                    marqueeObject.timeLeft, 
                    'linear', 
                    function(){
                        plugin.marqueeManager(marqueeObject);
                    });
        },
        callback: function() {
            // Cache onComplete option
            var onComplete = this.settings.onComplete;

            if ( typeof onComplete === 'function' ) {
                onComplete.call(this.element);
            }
        }

    });
    //end methods for plugin
    
    $.fn.SimpleMarquee = function (options) {
        this.each(function() {
            if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.SimpleMarquee.defaults = {
        autostart: true,
            property: 'value',
            onComplete: null,
            duration: 20000,
            padding: 10,
            marquee_class: '.marquee',
            container_class: '.simple-marquee-container',
            sibling_class: 0,
            hover: true
    };
    
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Would appreciate if anyone could point me some directions here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could come up with:

```js
Vue.filter('toFixed', (num, asset) => {
  if (typeof asset === 'number') return Number(num).toFixed(asset);
  return Number(num).toFixed((asset === 'USDT') ? 3 : 8);
});
Vue.filter('toMoney', num => {
  return Number(num).toFixed(0).replace(/./g, (c, i, a) => {
    return i && c !== "." && ((a.length - i) % 3 === 0) ? ',' + c : c;
  });
});

Vue.component('linechart', {
  props: {
    width: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400,
      required: true
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 40,
      required: true
    },
    values: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
      required: true
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cx: 0,
      cy: 0
    };
  },
  computed: {
    viewBox() {
      return '0 0 ' + this.width + ' ' + this.height;
    },
    chartPoints() {
      let data = this.getPoints();
      let last = data.length ? data[data.length - 1] : {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };
      let list = data.map(d => (d.x - 10) + ',' + d.y);
      this.cx = last.x - 5;
      this.cy = last.y;
      return list.join(' ');
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getPoints() {
      this.width = parseFloat(this.width) || 0;
      this.height = parseFloat(this.height) || 0;
      let min = this.values.reduce((min, val) => val < min ? val : min, this.values[0]);
      let max = this.values.reduce((max, val) => val > max ? val : max, this.values[0]);
      let len = this.values.length;
      let half = this.height / 2;
      let range = (max > min) ? (max - min) : this.height;
      let gap = (len > 1) ? (this.width / (len - 1)) : 1;
      let points = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        let d = this.values[i];
        let val = 2 * ((d - min) / range - 0.5);
        let x = i * gap;
        let y = -val * half * 0.8 + half;
        points.push({
          x,
          y
        });
      }
      return points;
    }
  },
  template: `
  <svg :viewBox="viewBox" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polyline class="cryptocolor" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" :points="chartPoints" />
    <circle class="cryptocolor" :cx="cx" :cy="cy" r="4" fill="#fff" stroke="none" />
  </svg>`,
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    endpoint: 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!ticker@arr',
    iconbase: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rainner/binance-watch/master/public/images/icons/',
    cache: {}, // coins data cache
    coins: [], // live coin list from api
    asset: 'USDT', // filter by base asset pair
    search: '', // filter by search string
    sort: 'Price', // sort by param
    order: 'desc', // sort order ( asc, desc )
    limit: 50, // limit list 
    status: 0, // socket status ( 0: closed, 1: open, 2: active, -1: error )
    sock: null, // socket inst
    cx: 0,
    cy: 0,
  },

  computed: {

    coinsList() {
      let list = this.coins.slice();
      let search = this.search.replace(/[^\s\w\-\.]+/g, '').replace(/[\r\s\t\n]+/g, ' ').trim();

      if (this.asset) {
        list = list.filter(i => i.asset === this.asset);
      }
      if (search && search.length > 1) {
        let reg = new RegExp('^(' + search + ')', 'i');
        list = list.filter(i => reg.test(i.token));
      }
      if (this.sort) {
        list = this.sortList(list, this.sort, this.order);
      }
      if (this.limit) {
        list = list.slice(0, this.limit);
      }
      return list;
    },

    loaderVisible() {
      return (this.status === 2) ? false : true;
    },

    sortLabel() {
      switch (this.sort) {

        case 'token':
          return 'Token';
        case 'percent':
          return 'Percent';
        case 'close':
          return 'Price';
        case 'change':
          return 'Change';
        case 'assetVolume':
          return 'Volume';
        case 'tokenVolume':
          return 'Volume';
        case 'trades':
          return 'Trades';
        default:
          return 'Default';
      }
    },
  },

  methods: {

    sortBy(key, order) {
      if (this.sort !== key) {
        this.order = order || 'asc';
      } else {
        this.order = (this.order === 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
      }
      this.sort = key;
    },
    filterAsset(asset) {
      this.asset = String(asset || 'BTC');
    },

    setLimit(limit) {
      this.limit = parseInt(limit) || 0;
    },
    onSockOpen(e) {
      this.status = 1; // open
      console.info('WebSocketInfo:', 'Connection open (' + this.endpoint + ').');
    },
    onSockClose(e) {
      this.status = 0; // closed
      console.info('WebSocketInfo:', 'Connection closed (' + this.endpoint + ').');
      setTimeout(this.sockInit, 10000); // try again
    },

    onSockError(err) {
      this.status = -1; // error
      console.error('WebSocketError:', err.message || err);
      setTimeout(this.sockInit, 10000); // try again
    },

    onSockData(e) {
      let list = JSON.parse(e.data) || [];

      for (let item of list) {
        let c = this.getCoinData(item);
        c.history = this.cache.hasOwnProperty(c.symbol) ? this.cache[c.symbol].history : this.fakeHistory(c.close);
        if (c.history.length > 100) c.history = c.history.slice(c.history.length - 100);
        c.history.push(c.close);
        this.cache[c.symbol] = c;
      }
      this.coins = Object.keys(this.cache).map(s => this.cache[s]);
      this.status = 2; // active
    },

    sockInit() {
      if (this.status > 0) return;
      try {
        this.status = 0; // closed
        this.sock = new WebSocket(this.endpoint);
        this.sock.addEventListener('open', this.onSockOpen);
        this.sock.addEventListener('close', this.onSockClose);
        this.sock.addEventListener('error', this.onSockError);
        this.sock.addEventListener('message', this.onSockData);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('WebSocketError:', err.message || err);
        this.status = -1; // error
        this.sock = null;
      }
    },
    sockClose() {
      if (this.sock) {
        this.sock.close();
      }
    },

    fakeHistory(close) {
      let num = close * 0.0001; // faction of current price
      let min = -Math.abs(num);
      let max = Math.abs(num);
      let out = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        let rand = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
        out.push(close + rand);
      }
      return out;
    },

    getCoinData(item) {
      let reg = /^([A-Z]+)(BTC|ETH|BNB|USDT|TUSD)$/;
      let symbol = String(item.s).replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '').toUpperCase();
      let token = symbol.replace(reg, '$1');
      let asset = symbol.replace(reg, '$2');
      let name = token;
      let pair = token + '/' + asset;
      let icon = this.iconbase + token.toLowerCase() + '_.png';
      let open = parseFloat(item.o);
      let high = parseFloat(item.h);
      let low = parseFloat(item.l);
      let close = parseFloat(item.c);
      let change = parseFloat(item.p);
      let percent = parseFloat(item.P);
      let trades = parseInt(item.n);
      let tokenVolume = Math.round(item.v);
      let assetVolume = Math.round(item.q);
      let sign = (percent >= 0) ? '+' : '';
      let arrow = (percent >= 0) ? '▲' : '▼';
      let info = [pair, close.toFixed(8), '(', arrow, sign + percent.toFixed(2) + '%', '|', sign + change.toFixed(8), ')'].join(' ');
      let style = '';

      if (percent > 0) style = 'cryptogain';
      if (percent < 0) style = 'cryptoloss';

      return {
        symbol,
        token,
        asset,
        name,
        pair,
        icon,
        open,
        high,
        low,
        close,
        change,
        percent,
        trades,
        tokenVolume,
        assetVolume,
        sign,
        arrow,
        style,
        info
      };
    },

    sortList(list, key, order) {
      return list.sort((a, b) => {
        let _a = a[key];
        let _b = b[key];

        if (_a && _b) {
          _a = (typeof _a === 'string') ? _a.toUpperCase() : _a;
          _b = (typeof _b === 'string') ? _b.toUpperCase() : _b;

          if (order === 'asc') {
            if (_a < _b) return -1;
            if (_a > _b) return 1;
          }
          if (order === 'desc') {
            if (_a > _b) return -1;
            if (_a < _b) return 1;
          }
        }
        return 0;
      });
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.sockInit();

    const gridList = document.querySelector('.cryptomain-grid-list');
    let gridListWidth = 0;
    const gridListInterval = setInterval(() => {

      if (gridList.children.length > 0) {

        for (let i of gridList.children) {
          gridListWidth += 311.2;
        }

        const cssAnimation = document.createElement('style');
        cssAnimation.type = 'text/css';
        const rules = document.createTextNode(`@keyframes marquee {
    0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(${-Math.abs(gridListWidth)}px); }
}`);
        cssAnimation.appendChild(rules);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssAnimation);
        clearInterval(gridListInterval);
      }
    }, 1)
  },

  destroyed() {
    this.sockClose();
  }
});
```

```css
.vw-sirat-search-icon i {
  color: #fff;
}

.placeholdercrypto::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: #1567d8;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

.placeholdercrypto:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #1567d8;
}

.placeholdercrypto::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: #1567d8;
}


/* CSS Document */

.cryptoif-small {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) {
  .cryptoif-small {
    display: initial;
  }
}

.cryptoif-medium {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .cryptoif-medium {
    display: initial;
  }
}

.cryptoif-large {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .cryptoif-large {
    display: initial;
  }
}

.cryptohidden,
[hidden],
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

.cryptodisabled,
[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.cryptocard {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #1e2126;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.cryptopush-top {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.cryptopush-right {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.cryptopush-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.cryptopush-left {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.cryptopush-all {
  margin: 1em;
}

.cryptopad-top {
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.cryptopad-right {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.cryptopad-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.cryptopad-left {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.cryptopad-all {
  padding: 1em;
}

.cryptoborder-top {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
}

.cryptoborder-right {
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
}

.cryptoborder-bottom {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
}

.cryptoborder-left {
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
}

.cryptoflex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.cryptoflex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cryptoflex-left {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.cryptoflex-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.cryptoflex-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.cryptoflex-space {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.cryptoflex-around {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.cryptoflex-top {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.cryptoflex-middle {
  align-items: center;
}

.cryptoflex-bottom {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.cryptoflex-1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.cryptoflex-2 {
  flex: 2;
}

.cryptoflex-3 {
  flex: 3;
}

.cryptoflex-4 {
  flex: 4;
}

.cryptoflex-5 {
  flex: 5;
}

.cryptotext-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.cryptotext-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.cryptotext-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.cryptotext-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}

.cryptotext-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cryptotext-lowercase {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.cryptotext-capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.cryptotext-underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.cryptotext-striked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.cryptotext-italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

.cryptotext-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 719px) {
  .cryptoif-mediumtopo {
    display: none;
  }
  .cryptoif-mediumtopo {
    display: block;
  }
  .cryptodropdown>ul {
    left: 0;
  }
  .cryptodropdown>ul {
    right: inherit;
  }
  .cryptotext-nowrap.cryptotext-condense.cryptoshadow-text {
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .cryptoif-mediumtopo {
    display: block;
  }
  .cryptoif-mediumtopo {
    display: none;
  }
  .cryptodropdown>ul {
    right: 0;
  }
  .cryptodropdown>ul {
    left: inherit;
  }
  .cryptotext-nowrap.cryptotext-condense.cryptoshadow-text {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
}

.cryptotext-nowrap.cryptotext-condense.cryptoshadow-text {
  font-family: fantasy;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 1px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), -1px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), -1px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}


/* Manter o nowrap, por causa dos botões */

.cryptotext-nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cryptotext-clip {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: #34b5eb;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.cryptotext-primary {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-block-start: 0.1em;
  margin-block-end: 0.1em;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.cryptotext-secondary {
  color: #20acea;
}

.cryptotext-grey {
  color: #5c6776;
}

.cryptotext-bright {
  color: #34b5eb;
  /*color: #f0f0f0;
     color: #1567d8; */
  margin-block-start: 0.1em;
  margin-block-end: 0.1em;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.cryptotext-faded {
  color: #004eb9;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.cryptotext-big {
  font-size: 120%;
  line-height: 1.212em;
}

.cryptotext-small {
  font-size: 70%;
  line-height: 1.14em;
}

.cryptotext-condense {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.cryptoshadow-box {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.cryptoshadow-text {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.cryptoform-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  background-color: #1567d8;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}

.cryptoform-input.dark {
  background-color: #000;
}

.cryptoform-input>input {
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #1567d8;
}

@keyframes dropdownShow {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(30px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.cryptodropdown {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cryptodropdown>ul {
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  transition: none;
  animation: dropdownShow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) forwards;
  top: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background-color: rgba(21, 103, 216, 0.19);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.18em);
  backdrop-filter: blur(0.18em);
}

.cryptodropdown>ul>li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px, #004eb9 0px 0px 1px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased.;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cryptodropdown .cryptotext-faded {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bolder
}

.cryptodropdown>ul>li+li {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50);
}

.cryptodropdown>ul>li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.cryptodropdown:hover>ul,
.cryptodropdown:active>ul {
  display: block;
}

.cryptoheader-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1e2126;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, transparent 60%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 999;
}

.cryptoheader-wrap .cryptoheader-row {
  height: 4em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.cryptoheader-wrap .cryptoheader-row .cryptodropdown {
  margin-left: 0.4em;
}

.cryptomain-wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0.7em;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: marquee 210s infinite linear;
}

.cryptomain-grid-list:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) {
  .cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  }
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item .cryptomain-grid-chart {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-left: solid 7px #1567d8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item.cryptogain {
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Cor do linha de ganho */

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item.cryptogain polyline.cryptocolor {
  stroke: rgba(50, 205, 50, 0.07);
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item.cryptogain circle.cryptocolor {
  fill: #32cd32;
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item.cryptogain .cryptocolor {
  color: #32cd32;
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item.cryptoloss {
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Cor do linha de perda */

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item.cryptoloss polyline.cryptocolor {
  stroke: rgb(220, 20, 60, 0.04);
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item.cryptoloss circle.cryptocolor {
  fill: #dc143c;
}


/* Cor do texto de perda */

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item.cryptoloss .cryptocolor {
  color: #dc143c;
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item .cryptomain-grid-info {
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
}

.cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item .cryptomain-grid-info img {
  width: auto;
  height: 16px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) {
  .cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item .cryptomain-grid-info img {
    height: 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .cryptomain-wrap .cryptomain-grid-list .cryptomain-grid-item .cryptomain-grid-info img {
    height: 32px;
  }
}

.cryptoloader-wrap {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.cryptoloader-wrap.cryptovisible {
  display: flex;
}

.cryptoloader-wrap .cryptoloader-content {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  background-color: #1e2126;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.cryptoloader-wrap .cryptoloader-content i {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 600%;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- vue root -->
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <!-- price list grid -->
  <main class="cryptomain-wrap">
    <div class="cryptomain-grid-list">
      <div class="cryptomain-grid-item marquee-text-text" v-for="c in coinsList" :key="c.symbol" :class="c.style">
        <div class="cryptomain-grid-chart">
          <linechart :width="190" :height="50" :values="c.history"></linechart>
        </div>
        <div class="cryptomain-grid-info cryptoflex-row cryptoflex-top cryptoflex-stretch">
          <div class="cryptopush-right">
            <img :src="c.icon" :alt="c.pair" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/123/wp-content/imagenspersonalizadas/lb-crypto-nopic.png';" />
          </div>
          <div class="cryptoflex-1 cryptoshadow-text">
            <div class="cryptoflex-row cryptoflex-top cryptoflex-space">
              <div class="cryptotext-left cryptotext-clip cryptopush-right">
                <h1 class="cryptotext-primary cryptotext-clip">{{ c.token }}<small class="cryptotext-faded cryptotext-small text-condense">/{{ c.asset }}</small></h1>
                <h2 class="cryptotext-bright cryptotext-clip">{{ c.close | toFixed( asset ) }}</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="cryptotext-right">
                <div class="cryptocolor cryptotext-big cryptotext-clip">{{ c.arrow }} {{ c.sign }}{{ c.percent | toFixed( 2 ) }}%</div>
                <div class="cryptotext-clip">{{ c.sign }}{{ c.change | toFixed( asset ) }} <small class="cryptotext-faded">24h</small></div>
                <div class="cryptotext-clip">{{ c.assetVolume | toMoney }} <small class="cryptotext-faded">Vol</small></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- socket loader -->
  <div class="cryptoloader-wrap" :class="{ 'visible': loaderVisible }">
    <div class="cryptoloader-content">
      <div v-if="status === 0"><i></i> <br /> Connecting to Socket API ...</div>
      <div v-else-if="status === 1"><i></i> <br /> Waiting for data from Socket API ...</div>
      <div v-else-if="status === 2"><i></i> <br /> Connected to the Socket API</div>
      <div v-else-if="status === -1"><i></i> <br /> Error connecting to the Socket API</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's a bit jittery, but I think this could be an issue with the socket updating or something, not sure.

To break-down how this works:

Add an animation to `.cryptomain-grid-list`: `animation: marquee 210s infinite linear`, infinite so it loops, linear so the motion is constant from right to left.

Then in the mounted hook:

```
    const gridList = document.querySelector('.cryptomain-grid-list');
    let gridListWidth = 0;
    const gridListInterval = setInterval(() => {

      if (gridList.children.length > 0) {

        for (let i of gridList.children) {
          console.log(i.offsetWidth)
          gridListWidth += 311.2;
        }

        const cssAnimation = document.createElement('style');
        cssAnimation.type = 'text/css';
        const rules = document.createTextNode(
          `@keyframes marquee {
            0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
            100% { transform: translateX(${-Math.abs(gridListWidth)}px); }
          }`);
        cssAnimation.appendChild(rules);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssAnimation);
        clearInterval(gridListInterval);
      }
    }, 1)
```

Set a variable which will tally up the width of each grid-item, add `setInterval` to run continually until the socket has loaded the data, then add the width of each item (300px) plus the width of the gap (0.7em is 11.2px) to the tally variable `gridListWidth`.

After you have the width of the grid, create a `style` element defining the animation and append it to the document head.

Hope that makes sense and at least points you in the right direction!

Comment: Is this is all created in vue, no jQuery?

Comment: I didn't add or remove any jQuery, so other than what was already there it's just Vue and CSS

Comment: I'm pretty new to Vue Js, it was only recently that I realized how hungry it is for the DOM.
Your code is working just as I need. Can you point me directions on how I can create a `play/pause`, `previous` and `next` button?
Also, is there any way to join the two extremities of the bar, this way there won't be a huge gap when the animation ends?

Comment: Also pause on hover.

Comment: Pause on hover is easy enough: `.cryptomain-grid-list:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}`, added to my post

Comment: Looking into previous and next, sounds like a rabbit-hole I don't fancy going down. You'd have to use JS and alter the timing/direction of the animations but it might be worth looking into something that can do it for you. I've heard a lot about [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/) but I've never used it myself. Could be what you're after.

Comment: Thank you so far for all the help you've provided. I've decided I'm going to finish this in vue, since jQuery is giving me too much of a headache. Can you tell me a website where I can find a database of vue resources, besides the one I've described (The Progressive JavaScript Framework https://vuejs.org )?

Comment: No problem, [Vue Mastery](https://www.vuemastery.com/) and [Vue School](https://vueschool.io/) are the main ones out there